# SSRS, Parameters, Default value as latest record

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services, visual-studio-2005, default-value

I´m using MS Visual Studio 2005.

How do you set the default value of a parameter to be the latest record available.
That is the newest record.

 See Image below, the default value should be the top date (Dec. 2011).
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can set the default value as an expression and use the `Last` function over your dataset.

- [Last Function reference at Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283113.aspx)

Comment: I tried the following but didn´t work:

=last(Parameters!Time.Value(0))

=last(First(Fields!YearMonth.Value, "Time"))